# Is an object kept in memory if one of its attributes is still referenced?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

Lets say there is this huge object which contains a large number of other huge objects as its attributes, but one attribute is a very small object.

```
class HugeObject  
{
   private HugeObject1 x1;
   private HugeObject2 x2;
        :
        :
   private HugeObject1000  x1000;
   private SmallObject1    s1;

   public SmallObject1 getSmallObject()
   {
       return s1;
   }
}
```

The following code snippet will create a new object based on the small object (`SmallObject1`). The `HugeObject` in the `runThis()` routine goes out of scope, but the `SmallObject1` attribute is returned.

```
public class Test 
{
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          SmallOjbect1 so = runThis();
          //Application continues to run here for a long time.

      }

      public SmallObject1 runThis()
      {
          HugeObject ho = new HugeObject();
                :
          //Do some calculations, call other procedures....

          return ho.getSmallObject();
      }
}
```

Is this scenario, is only the `SmallObject1` kept in memory or is `HugeObject` also in memory as `SmallObject1` is its attribute.

Even though `HugeObject` is out of scope, I am not certain if it will remain in memory since one of its attributes are still in memory.

Answer (score 4):

As long as no references to the `HugeObject` instance remain, it will become eligible for garbage collection. This doesn't mean that it will be garbage collected immediately though (that is up to the JVM).

One thing to watch out for is having (possibly indirect) references from the `SmallObject` instance back to the `HugeObject` instance. This could happen, for example, if `SmallObject` is an inner class of `HugeObject`. ([This article](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-language/inner-class-constructor.html) explains the mechanics in some detail.)

If there is a reference chain from the `SmallObject` instance back to the `HugeObject` instance, the latter will be kept around for as long as the former exists.